# In Elm, a GET request can't have a body, or is it?

Tags: request, http-post, elm, http-get, payload

### `Http.request` seems to ignore `body` when the method is `GET`

```
init : () -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
init _ =
    ( Loading
    , Http.request
        { method = "GET"
        , headers = []
        , url = "http://127.0.0.1"
        , body = Http.stringBody "text/plain" "Hello World!"
        , expect = Http.expectWhatever Sent
        , timeout = Nothing
        , tracker = Nothing
        }
    )
```

The sent request has no body (when inspected with browser development tool).

```
init : () -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
init _ =
    ( Loading
    , Http.request
        { method = "POST" {- CHANGED TO POST -}
        , headers = []
        , url = "http://127.0.0.1"
        , body = Http.stringBody "text/plain" "Hello World!"
        , expect = Http.expectWhatever Sent
        , timeout = Nothing
        , tracker = Nothing
        }
    )
```

But when the method is changed to `"POST"`, it works ! The body contains `"Hello World!"`.

The API I try to communicate with requires an `application/json` body in a `GET` request. Help me  !

PS: Here is what the documentations says:

> `emptyBody : Body`
>
> Create an empty body for your Request. This is useful for GET requests
> and POST requests where you are not sending any data.

Which is not clear, because it can be interpreted in two different ways:

*This is useful for GET requests and { POST requests where you are not sending any data } .*

Or:

*This is useful for { GET requests and POST requests } where you are not sending any data.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Elm actually does add the body to the request, but the browser doesn't send it.

To see this, compile this Elm program:

```
module Main exposing (main)

import Platform
import Http

main =
    Platform.worker
        { init = \() -> ((), Http.request
            { method = "GET"
            , headers = []
            , url = "https://catfact.ninja/fact"
            , body = Http.stringBody "text/plain" "hi"
            , expect = Http.expectWhatever (\_ -> ())
            , timeout = Nothing
            , tracker = Nothing
            })
        , update = \() () -> ((), Cmd.none)
        , subscriptions = \() -> Sub.none
        }
```

without optimisation flags to get an `index.html` file. Part of this file is:

```
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.addEventListener('error', function() { done($elm$http$Http$NetworkError_); });
        xhr.addEventListener('timeout', function() { done($elm$http$Http$Timeout_); });
        xhr.addEventListener('load', function() { done(_Http_toResponse(request.expect.b, xhr)); });
        $elm$core$Maybe$isJust(request.tracker) && _Http_track(router, xhr, request.tracker.a);

        try {
            xhr.open(request.method, request.url, true);
        } catch (e) {
            return done($elm$http$Http$BadUrl_(request.url));
        }

        _Http_configureRequest(xhr, request);

        request.body.a && xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', request.body.a);
        xhr.send(request.body.b);
```

If you open this file in the browser and step through this part of it in the debugger, you can see that Elm actually does put the given body "hi" in the `request.body.b` value, passed to `xhr.send`.

But if you then look in the Network tab in the browser console, you can see that the request doesn't contain a body.

So this is the browser stripping out the body with GET requests, not Elm.

Answer (score 6):

According to the HTTP specification, `GET` should not have a body. See for example [its description on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET), which says:

> **Note**: Sending body/payload in a `GET` request may cause some existing
> implementations to reject the request — while not prohibited by the
> specification, the semantics are undefined. It is better to just avoid
> sending payloads in `GET` requests.